# Dajax - get a simple value from a function usinf add_data: Uncaught ReferenceError client-side

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, dajaxice, dajax

I just want to return a simple value from an ajax function using dajax but it seems not so simple:

```
## python
@dajaxice_register
def get_selected_option_value(request, id):
    """
    return my value
    """
    dajax = Dajax()
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        value = item.price
        value = "%.2f" % value
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        value = 0
    dajax.add_data(value, 'get_value')
    return dajax.json()

// js
function getValFromOption(option){
    Dajaxice.gpf2.get_selected_option_value(Dajax.process, {'id':$(option).attr('value')});
}

function get_value(data){
    return data;
}
```

I still get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: get_value is not defined
```

Is there any simple way to return a value from a Dajax function and store it in a js variable?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to store a value to javascript from Dajax is simply:

```
dajax = Dajax()
value = 1
dajax.script('var i = %d;' % value)
return dajax.json()
```

Comment: I need to get the value in the js context. I've tried with your code server-side, and client side with:

`var p = Dajaxice.gpf2.get_selected_option_value(Dajax.process, {'id':$(option).attr('value')});
        console.log(p)`

but I still haven't found how to get the value...

Comment: You asked how to  store a value from a Dajax function in a javascript variable. Run that python code and it will assign 1 to `i`.
The `script` command will run any javascript code you pass to it.

If you want to